# Call on an initialized tf.keras.Model gives dimension mismatch on Dropout layer within the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dropout

I'm trying to save a TF Keras Model with 2 dropout layers included within the model (This is an Attention model - first dropout is for the attention weights and 2nd is for the overall output of the layer). However, when I use this model and call it using 2 parameters, I get an error saying that there are dimensionality mismatches between my inputs and I'm not sure where this is coming from.

I can't really post the code. I know this is kind of vague, but I can post the traceback below. Any suggestion of what to check on/what could be going wrong that I should consider would really be appreciated. Thanks!

My general code would be:

```py
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(...), name="inputs")
mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(..., name="mask")

# perform attention computation
attention = ...
attention = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(attention)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=..., activation="relu")(attention + inputs)
outputs = Normalize(outputs)

model = tf.keras.Model([inputs, mask], outputs)

model_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(...), name="model_inputs")
model_outputs = tf.keras.Dropout(rate=0.1)(model_inputs)
model_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(...), name="model_mask")
model_outputs = model([outputs, model_mask])
```

The error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 562, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 822, in call
    mask=masks)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1010, in _run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1822, in call
    return self._make_op(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1837, in _make_op
    c_op = ops._create_c_op(graph, self.node_def, inputs, control_inputs=[])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1664, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 256 and 0 for 'encode_layer_0/tf_op_layer_tony/cond/dropout/random_uniform/mul/tony/cond/dropout/random_uniform/mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,?,256], [0].
```

edit: Fixed the "code". I meant to write model_inputs. The code I posted here isn't the actual code, it's just sorta similar. It might very well be something in where I do the attention weights calculations but I'm not sure what to look for since the code is kind of lengthy. Thanks!